# show notification in every 3 sec in android

Tags: java, android, notifications

I want create a service within my app that every 3 sec creates a notification. i create this code but it works only one time when i launch my app. i want get notification in every 3 sec!! even when i close my app i get notifications!! ( because of this i create service)
please help me.

```
public class notifService extends Service {
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
private static final int HELLO_ID = 1;

    @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
        final Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, notifService.class);

        scheduler.schedule(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Look up the notification manager server
                NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                // Create your notification
                int icon = R.drawable.fifi;
                CharSequence tickerText = "Hello";
                long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
                Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText,when);
                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                CharSequence contentTitle = "My notification";
                CharSequence contentText = "Hello World!";
                PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(notifService.this, 0, intent1, 0);
                notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle,contentText, pIntent);
                // Send the notification
                nm.notify(HELLO_ID, notification);
            }
        }, 3, SECONDS);
    }

    @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Comment: i think you have to call service after every 3 sec from your activity... n write rest of the notification code in on start...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `schedule` method you're using *executes a one-shot action*.

You need to use [`ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleWithFixedDelay%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29):

> Creates and executes a periodic action that becomes enabled first
>   after the given initial delay, and subsequently with the given delay
>   between the termination of one execution and the commencement of the
>   next.

Try this:

```
scheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          // your code
        }
    }, 3, 3, SECONDS);
```

Note the extra `3` in the method call as this methods expects four arguments.

Comment: can you give me a real example? i'm not able modify my code to do this. thanks